# How to solve "Microsoft Visual Studio (VS)" error "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server"

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

**PROBLEM**

In some cases "[Microsoft Visual Studio (VS)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng)" when you use "[Microsoft Internet Information Services Express (IIS)](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)" and you have attached web site project to IIS after run Build shown this error message

`Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server`.

How can I solve it if exception message does not shown nothing more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pre-Requirements**

The best step is catch what exactly is going on.

1. Download and use for it "[Sysinternals Process Monitor (PM)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)".
2. Run PM and create filter `'Process Name' 'is' 'iisexpress.exe'`. Now you show capture events only from IIS.
3. Run building your VS project with key <kbd>F5</kbd> and watch PM results.
4. Open with double click first row with `Operation = Process Start` and look detail for full parameters to run IIS especially "Command line".
5. Open "[Command Line Interface (CLI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)" called "[Command shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx)" with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> write "cmd" put IIS command line value and run with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now you see the exact error:

   ```
    "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"  /config:"C:\Users\{user_name}\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config"  /site:"{project_name}" /apppool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
   ```

**SOLUTION**

**Case "apppool"**

> The following switch requires a value: `apppool`

1. Open file

   ```
    %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`
   ```
2. Find in section `sites > site` your named project or by `bindingInformation` by attached from VS. Add to section `application` another parameter `applicationPool` from version what you use for your project.

   ```
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
   ```
3. Now test it, close fully VS, open project again and build.

**Case "config"**

1. "Remove WebMatrix" or "Create symlink" or replace it on that place.

---

**Ref**

- Thanks to [Finbar Ryan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/finbar_ryan/archive/2013/01/02/debugging-the-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-from-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

Comment: I learned so much about how to troubleshoot IIS issues with this one post. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I helped @AnilNatha 

Answer (score 0):

In my case i tried every post I found on net and nothing works, last thing I done is to change option on project right click/ use visual studio web server  and all works well now...

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost everything but it didn't work. Then I restarted my computer. and iis express worked :) I don't know maybe a reboot was needed for what I did.