# How to solve “Microsoft Visual Studio (VS)” error “Unable to connect to the configured development Web server”

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, access-rights

**PROBLEM**

If you start using "[Microsoft Internet Information Services Express (IIS)](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)" from "[Microsoft Visual Studio (VS)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng)" you may get when you run Build this error message

`Unable to connect to the configured development Web server`.

`Failed to register URL "http://{ip_addr}:{port}/" for site "{project_name}" application "/". Error description: Access is denied. (0x80070005)`

What kind of rights is it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

This means that you are missing the right for using it. Create it with [Netsh Commands for Hypertext Transfer Protocol](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725882%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) > [add urlacl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

1. Open "[Command Line Interface (CLI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)" called "[Command shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx)" with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> write "cmd"
2. Open CLI windows like administrator with mouse context menu on opened windows or icon ["Run as administrator"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx)
3. Insert command to register url

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://{ip_addr}:{port}/ user=everyone
```

---

**Note**

- *For remove you can use: `netsh http delete urlacl url=http://{ip_addr}:{port}/`*
- *If not work restart [Microsoft Windows (WIN)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/home) and then open project and build again.*
- *Sometimes these symptoms may be the same like ["Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292788/how-to-solve-microsoft-visual-studio-vs-error-unable-to-launch-the-iis-expr/19292790).*

Comment: With VS2013 on Win 7 all I had to do was re-start Visual Studio, no need to reboot. Thanks!

Comment: I agree Blake in WIN7 enough it to me the last week too.

Comment: Great answer (+1), but why does this happen in the first place. Everything was Just Working(tm) and then, woke up the next day for work...and it wasn't. Seems very strange.

Comment: This worked for me, note that I got to run cmd.exe as administrator.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. Restarting had no effect. This worked. However, this command requires elevated privileges so you have to run the command prompt as administrator

Comment: I also had to run VS as administrator to make it work.

Comment: Dear Microsoft, why is it I have to perform one or more web searches on random Visual Studio failures nearly every single workday?

Comment: If you get an error saying `Create SDDL failed, Error: 1332`, then check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856394/2570315 It seems the user is language dependant.

Answer (score 50):

Delete autogenerated config files on the project folder.

1. Close Visual Studio projects.
2. Delete .vs folder on project folder that includes applicationhost.config file.

Visual Studio will generate a new config for this project.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Changing the port number and rebuilding the solution didn't work until I deleted the .vs folder.

Comment: This saved my life :)

Comment: This solution saved me headaches! From the Solution explorer in Visual Studio, right-click on the solution name for properties, and then click on Open Folder in File Explorer: that's where you'll find the folder to delete.

Comment: this should be answer

Comment: nice trick, maybe these days it's better solution - if more people vote for it I select it @Waqarali

Comment: Thanks, great solution

Comment: Well that fixed it for me! - everything else failed miserably. Must be some strange corruption when changing PCs accessing the project - or if you switch between "on-network" and "VPN" connection to access project files. +1 from me.

Comment: Saved my life too.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, after many tries :D

Answer (score 23):

Opening Visual Studio as **administrator** will fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah. Close Visual Studio, Start as Administrator. Problem solved for me.

Comment: I would call this a workaround, not a fix. Since when you need to be administrator to debug with Visual Studio???

Comment: This is still a problem w/ VS '15 & '17. This answer is the only one that seems to work. Right click shortcut-->properties-->advanced-->check run as administrator. Never look back.

Comment: @trevorc wrong! In fact my `applicationhost.config` file is not used anymore, I can delete the file, it's not automatically recreated. And this is a problem because I want to configure other bindings like `en.localhost.com`.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the error by changing the **port** for the project.

I did the following steps:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Go to properties.
3. Go to Server tab.
4. On tab section, change the project URL for other port, like 8080 or 3000.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

We solved this problem with deleting **.vs folder** on project folder and deleting **temporary ASP.NET files**.

```
1. Close the Visual Studio.
2. Delete .vs folder on project folder that includes applicationhost.config file.
3. Delete temporary ASP.NET Files located: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root
```

Comment: if that really works for everybody after 4years it's nice

Answer (score 4):

I am using visual studio 2015.
Deleting **.vs** folder in the project folder helped me to fix this. You must close the visual studio first.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

If you use a `newer version` of Visual Studio, you may not have this problem. I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 and it works great.

**Solution 2**

You can solve this problem by changing the project's `port number`.

Because the reason is a port number conflict with some other application.

I had the same issue and fixed by doing that (by changing the port number).

I had solved this here : [Changing project port number in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013)

If you use a different version of Visual Studio; you may also change the port number by project's Properties Window in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Changing the port number does not solve the problem for me.

Comment: I had this problem and was fiddller using the same port

Comment: Changing the port number fixed this for me +1

Comment: Change the port number of project and fixed problem for me. Thanks :*

Answer (score 2):

For me I tried a few of the above - run as administrator, check firewall.

For me it was the IIS Express configuration.  A little bit of a "just get it working" fix without much investigation, but deleting the folder IIS Express is located under

```
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\iisexpress
```

Not sure what caused the issue for my VS2013 - but I am constantly flipping between VS2013 sites in IIS and IIS Express.

**NOTE:** When I forget to run VS2013 as Administrator, my Local IIS project gets inserted in the IIS Express applicationhost.config file, which fails to open the web project.  Which is really frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me in VS2003 and VS2017 on Windows 8

1. Run the command in CMD with admin rights

   `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::`
2. Then go to regedit path `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters]` and check if the value has been added.
   [image]

For more details check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/iis-express-failed-to-register-url-access-is-denied

Comment: After trying everything, including adding and removing the urlacl with the netsh command, and deleting the .vs folder, I was ready to reinstall IISExpress when I got this solution to work for me. This was not the first time it happened and the removal of the urlacl resolved my first instance, but not this time around. Thank you @Serge and I will keep this on a permalink.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this just now, in the system tray (bottom right) you can click ion the IIS icon and stop the current site, then it allowed me to run.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered and resolved this in VS2013 on Windows 7. It is a Web Application Project that doesn't use SSL. But when I examined the Properties Window (F4), SSL was enabled. Setting SSL to false resolved the issue.

However, when verifying before posting this answer, turning it back on did not cause a recurrence of the problem. So it might be that anything that writes to that preferences resolves the problem, rather than the details of what was written.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by restarting my computer. I'm guessing that this port was being occupied by a process that needed to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried many ways and still have this problem, **take a look at your firewall settings** and make sure it does not block Visual Studio or IIS !!

This worked for me!

Comment: Good point for create "Pre-requirements" - better for contribution like this is comments - you can still get point if it is valuable. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost all the options above, none of them worked for my scenario. Finally I was forced to uninstall IIS Express, re-start the machine, and install the same version again from Microsoft.

Anyway thanks for all the suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on Windows 7 and VS  2013 while viewing a project on the browser after build. I only had to close the browser "Chrome" then made sure that the port is not in use in my Network Activities using some utility then tried again and worked without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Bruno's answer I ended up registering the same port for localhost. Otherwise VS2015 was giving me Access Denied error on server start.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:{port}/ user=everyone
```

May be it's because I have binding for localhost in aplicationhost.config also.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10, project source control was managed in TFS Online.

None of this worked form me, issue appeared after a reformat of Windows 10 and subsequent reinstall of VStudio 2015. I mapped projects to the same folder (residual folders and files were still there.)

Deleting the entire old project (specifically the .VS) and then remapping it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just update Visual Studio, this is the simplest solution that worked for me.

Comment: maybe after 6 years they have fixed it :-)

Comment: @BgBruno it's possible. are you ok now :)?

Answer (score 0):

Delete .vs folder on project folder and  Delete temporary ASP.NET Files located:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

And the Open the Visual Studio in Admin mode and run the program

Answer (score 0):

i created a new solution and imported the projects.