# Unable to connect to the configured development web sever

Tags: c#, web, visual-studio-2015, server

How to solve "Unable to connect to the configured development web server on" in vs2015? p.s I've checked the answers of similar questions and it didn't help.

[This image is from visual studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWSeo.jpg) where every time i try to view the website in browser this window pops up

Comment: Provide relevant code please.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well, you should post what piece of code gave you trouble.

Comment: it's not a specific piece of code...this happens when i try to press the start button and view the website on browser, It used to work properly until today's morning although i didn't change anything in the code

Comment: Well stuff doesn't really break magically. At least not in the world of software.

Comment: well I added a webservice reference but immediately deleted it when this problem showed up...so technically i didn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried closing any stray processes which might still be running? Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990033/unable-to-connect-to-asp-net-development-server-issue

Comment: If you are using IIS (or if you know the executable name of the webserver you are using), try going to Debug > Attach to Process.  Is the webserver executable in the list?  If not, you may need to run VS as administrator.  I do not recall right off-hand, but there are a number of instances where elevated privileges are required to connect to the webserver.

Comment: quirk, I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: CodeWarrior, I'm running it directly from the file system (not using iis) and I really don't have any idea on how to run vs as an administrator

Comment: When starting Visual Studio, right click the VS2015 icon, choose Run as Administrator, click Yes on the UAC prompt.  Is this project the only project in your solution?  Does it have any dependencies, third party or otherwise?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work...yes it is the only project in the solution

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved the problem, it seems that I was missing the right of using the server (or something like that) 
Any way you can find the solution in this link 
[How to solve “Microsoft Visual Studio (VS)” error “Unable to connect to the configured development Web server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293572/how-to-solve-microsoft-visual-studio-vs-error-unable-to-connect-to-the-conf)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that once higher version of VS installed at the system and after that working on vs lower version ,Just Delete the IIS express folder created  in .../documants 
it will run

Answer (score 0):

Running Visual Studio 2015 as Administrator working fine for me