# View in browser is not working in one solution

Tags: browser, view

There is a another article with a similar issue with many solutions.
[How to solve “Microsoft Visual Studio (VS)” error “Unable to connect to the configured development Web server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293572/how-to-solve-microsoft-visual-studio-vs-error-unable-to-connect-to-the-conf)
However none of them worked for me. what solved it for me was a very dumb solution ( I think) .
I do not have the points to comment there , so I am creating a new post , hopefully it will help someone

The solution was configured on this port http://localhost:49810 , changed the port to a lower number 1800 and lo & behold it worked.